# Upgrade from rails 3.1.3 to rails 3.2.1. Error with assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-3.1

I try to upgrade my application from rails 3.1.3 to rails 3.2.1 and I have a problem with assets.

I have this kind of error :

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/logos/opera_logo.png"):
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

Rails don't find all my assets but I think than they are in the right folder (app/assets/images/logos/ for example).

I followed this guide for upgrade my system : http://railscasts.com/episodes/318-upgrading-to-rails-3-2?view=asciicast. It was running very well with rails 3.1. I don't find any other change to do. What can I do?

This is my Gemfile :

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.8.1'
  gem 'autotest-rails', '4.1.1'
  gem 'spork', '0.8.5'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.4.0'
  gem 'email_spec', '1.2.1'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.2.1'
  gem 'launchy', '2.0.5'
  gem 'pickle', '0.4.10'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '0.7.0'
  gem 'simplecov', '0.5.4'
  gem 'simplecov-rcov', '0.2.3'
  gem "mocha", '0.10.0'
  gem 'capybara-firebug', '0.0.10'
  gem "prawn", '0.8.4'
end

group :development do
  gem "nifty-generators", '0.4.6'
end

gem 'active_reload', '0.6.1'
gem "galetahub-simple_captcha", '0.1.3', :require => "simple_captcha"
gem 'authlogic', '3.1.0'
gem 'meta_search', '1.1.3'
gem 'naive_bayes', :git => 'git://github.com/reddavis/Naive-Bayes.git'
```

This is my development.rb :

```
Onopia::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request.  This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

  # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Expands the lines which load the assets
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
end
```

And this is my application.rb :

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module Onopia
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

    # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
    # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
    # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

    # Activate observers that should always be running.
    # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    config.i18n.default_locale = :fr

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'

    # Configure generators values. Many other options are available,
    # be sure to check the documentation.
    #config.generators do |g|
    #  g.test_framework :rspec, :fixture => false
    #end

    config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  end
end
```

Edit: a better example.

I want to view this file :

> app/assets/javascripts/application.js

When I go to this url :

> http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js

And I have this error :

```
Started GET "/assets/application.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-06 17:04:38 -0500
Served asset /application.js - 404 Not Found (1ms)

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application.js"):
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

Thanks a lot and have a nice day.

Comment: You say the asset is in `app/assets/images`, but you are calling  the image from the `app/assets/logos`

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake. My file is here : app/assets/images/logos/opera_logo.png. I edited my post.

Comment: I wonder if editing a post changed the RoutingError message. According to your log above the image you refer to is not in the `assets/images` folder, but in `assets/logos`. Change the location of your file to `assets/logos` or better find the referring link and change it to match `assets/images/opera_logo.png`

Comment: If the above will not help, check the assets generation by trying, for example `http://localhost:3000/assets/application.css`. You shall see if your styles were generated under `assets` folder. If they weren't, check if assets pipeline is at all enabled.

Comment: Sorry, I choosed the wrong example. This is the same with application.css which is locate at this place app/assets/stylesheets/application.css. I have this error : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application.css")

Comment: Would you show the contents of your Gemfile and your development.rb file (assuming you run your code in dev mode)?

Comment: I edit my post to add Gemfile, development.rb and application.rb

Comment: I edit my post to put a better example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently some gem dependency is broken and `bundle exec rails server` should resolve this. This should be run without `sudo ...` unless you usually work with your app with root privileges (which is not good). Check the files/folders permissions in your rails root, which might have been broken by misusing `sudo` commands earlier. While in development you hardly need any root privileges.

Other than that, [similar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826154/rails-3-1rc4-asset-pipeline-broke-after-ruby-update-how-to-re-activate-configur) have also appeared before and the answer was to update your entire gemset, primarily sprockets and rails. Your configuration files look okay to me and I can't reproduce the error.

If that does not help, I would create a new rails app, check the assets pipeline working there with the same gemset that you have and manually cross-check all config files.

There are various debugging tools for routing too, but try the above first.

Comment: I installed a new gemset, with RVM, and it works! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I started rails server with `bundle exec rails s` and it works. The strage thing about this error is that other assets (javascripts, stylesheets) work fine with `rails s` but images don't.

Comment: @Giovanni You are giving too few details to understand. Please, start a new question explaining your situation. Make sure to include your `Gemfile` and calls to images assets that do not work and full error messages.

Answer (score 13):

I hit a similar problem that I resolved by removing the `active_reload` gem.

Comment: This is an issue for Rails < 3.2 projects going to 3.2+ ...the homepage of the project says `active_reload` is incompatible with Rails 3.2 moving forward.

Comment: After few hours of searching - I was found. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered something similar earlier.  How are you referencing them?  Is it an image_tag failing or CSS reference failing?

If your file is here `/app/assets/images/logos/opera_logo.png` then the following references should work.

From an html.erb file: `<%= image_tag('logos/opera_logo.png') %>`

From an scss file: `background: url(image_path("logos/opera_logo.png"))`

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your Gemfile and restart the server, as per: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#upgrading-from-old-versions-of-rails

```
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   "~> 3.2.3"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.2.1"
  gem 'uglifier'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

New to Rails, but for my images located in the directory `../app/assets/images` e.g. "rails.png"
the proper CSS reference for a background image is: `background: white url(rails.png) repeat-y;` (options shown)

Even though it is in the images folder, with rails 3.2.6 (version I'm using), you don't put the images part of the directory.