# rails 3.2.1 very slow in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, passenger, ruby-1.9.3

Since i upgrade my app on my development server, the request are terribly slow. Event if the log seems to render quite quickly, it take 10-15 second for the loading to be complete (event if the page is already fully loaded)

My configuration :

- Rails 3.2.1
- Ruby 1.9.3-p125 (rvm)
- Standalone Passenger (3.0.11)

I do not have this kind of issue on my development machine, so i guess the problem is not coming from my application

Comment: After some search, it occurs that application.js is not served properly (incomplete file) - does this sound familiar to anybody?

Comment: it has to be something with 'rails asset pipeline' - google that, also did you checked that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826154/rails-3-1rc4-asset-pipeline-broke-after-ruby-update-how-to-re-activate-configur

Comment: Are application assets being served from the server? Are logs indicating that js/css/images being served?

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem. Found this question ( [Slow assets ruby 1.9.3, macos, rails 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720572/slow-assets-ruby-1-9-3-macos-rails-3-2) ) which helped me discover it was chrome where the problem was occurring. Still don't know why, or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was Rails Panel extension that was slowing Chrome.  I just disabled it and it the app became 3 times faster.