# Rails development environment takes 5-10 seconds to load each asset file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

Working with Rails 3, each page load can take anywhere from 10 seconds to a few minutes to load; looking at the output, it seems something is happening behind the scenes, as the time served is listed as 0ms for the vast majority of these files, and yet between each of them it will take 5-10+ seconds to progress to the next one.  Several sources recommended RailsDevTweaks, and I have that installed and running, and it does indeed print a message of "RailsDevTweaks: Skipping ActionDispatch::Reloader hooks for this request.", but that doesn't seem to be doing much.  Any thoughts here?  Let me know what information I can provide to help solve this problem.

Comment: i am not running Pow.  There is no `tmp/always_restart.txt` in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Make sure you're not using a **host.local** tld.

Check out these answers for more details:

[Slow assets ruby 1.9.3, macos, rails 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720572/slow-assets-ruby-1-9-3-macos-rails-3-2)

https://serverfault.com/questions/322747/can-a-long-etc-hosts-file-slow-dns-lookup

Comment: Yes, this ended up being the problem - I forgot I had posted this question!

Comment: Amazing. I had been developing in safari for a month because of that. Going back to chrome dev tools feels so good.